# How to call a stored procedure that is in another database In snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a procedure that saves the current state of the database and schema
Afterwards it changes the schema and database and performs some operation
Once that is done it calls back the previously saved database and schema
I have procedures do exactly this however, when I try to call procedures from the other database it does not allow me

Here is an example snippet

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test()
  RETURNS VARCHAR
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  COMMENT = 'Performs operations'
  EXECUTE AS CALLER
  AS
  $$
    var v_sqlCode = 'CALL SAVE_STATE()';
    try{
         var sqlStmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText :  v_sqlCode});
         var sqlRS = sqlStmt.execute(); 
    }catch(err){
         errMessage =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;     
    }

    var v_sqlCode = 'USE SCHEMA ANOTHER_DB.PUBLIC`; 

    try{
         var sqlStmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText :  v_sqlCode});
         var sqlRS = sqlStmt.execute(); 
    }catch(err){
         errMessage =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;     
    }
    
   var v_sqlCode = 'CALL OLDDB.SCHEMA.RESET_STATE()`;

    try{
         var sqlStmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText :  v_sqlCode});
         var sqlRS = sqlStmt.execute(); 
    }catch(err){
         errMessage =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;     
    }
$$;

}
```

The error I get is that the reset function doesn't exist in the other database so I can't switch back, how do I go about this?

Comment: What happen if you always specify a three-part qualifier ( DB.SCHEMA.SP ) on the call to the SP?

Comment: @GregPavlik that actually ended up being the solution! Thank you so much for always helping , I am forever grateful

Answer (score 0):

Please use full identifier for the database Object, i.e the Stored Proc

```
call DB_NAME.SCHEMA_NAME.SP_NAME
```